# Sql Stored Procedure / Php issue

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am having a problem getting a result set from my Sql Server 2008 stored procedure when calling it using PHP.  When I execute the stored procedure from within sql, I get the results, so I know the issue isnt with the stored procedure(below). 
**Sql Stored Procedure**

```
USE [HRAPPS]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_GetSecurityAnswer]    Script Date: 10/21/2011 08:38:35 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetSecurityAnswer]
(
    @ThisContactId INT, @ThisQuestionId INT, @ThisAnswer varchar(255)
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT 
            a.Cont_id,
            a.QuestionId
    FROM    dbo.sec_answers a
    WHERE   a.cont_id = @ThisContactId and
            a.QuestionId = @ThisQuestionId and
            lower(a.Response) = lower(@ThisAnswer)

END
```

Here is the PHP code that calls the stored procedure.  Note: The connection to the database works, so I know that it isnt the issue.

**PHP Code **

```
if(!$dbCon=mssql_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS)) 
{
   $error = "Unable to Connect to Database. Please Try Again Later.";
} 
else 
{
   $stmt = mssql_init("sp_GetSecurityAnswer", $dbCon);
   mssql_bind($stmt, "@ThisContactId", $_SESSION['thisContId'], SQLINT4, false, false, 6);
   mssql_bind($stmt, "@ThisQuestionId", $_SESSION['SecQuestion'], SQLINT4, false, false, 2);
   mssql_bind($stmt, "@ThisAnswer", $_SESSION['ThisAnswer'], SQLVARCHAR, false, false, 255);
   $Security_Verification_Result = mssql_execute($stmt, false);     

   IF(!mssql_num_rows($Security_Verification_Result)) 
   {
     ECHO "You have Incorrectly answered your selected Security Verification Question, Please go back and try again";
    EXIT();
   }
   ELSE
   {        
     header("Location: some_url?userfullname=".$_SESSION['userfullname'] .'&cont_id='.$_SESSION['ThisContId']);
   }
}   
exit();
```

**End of PHP Code**

So what am I missing guys(and gals too!)??  any help would be greatly appreciated :D
thanks in advance

Comment: What output did you get, and what did you expect?

Comment: Care to tell us what the problem is?  An error message, unexpected output, etc?

Comment: did you echo out your `$_SESSION['...']` values to make sure you are actually passing in the same values you think you are?

Comment: What is being returned? Echo mssql_get_last_message() after your execute line to find out more about any errors.

Comment: to Dems and KM - I am expecting one result from the stored procedure.  When I execute the stored procedure from within sql management studio using the same parameters that are being fed in using the bind statement, I get a result; when this executes witin php, there are no results.  I echo'd the variables before the stored procedure is executed and they are there with the correct/expected values.  I even tried to add a single quote before and after the string parameter with no help

Comment: Have you used `GRANT execute on phpuser` in SSMS to make sure the login your PHP app user has execute rights on the DB?

Comment: Hi SirTapTap - yes, the phpuser has all the necessary rights.  There are many calls to stored procedures throughout the site and they all work fine - less this particular one. Thats what has me baffled; this call to the stored procedure is like all the others!  grrrrrrrrr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code:

```
mssql_bind($stmt, "@ThisContactId", $_SESSION['thisContId'], SQLINT4, false, false, 6);
mssql_bind($stmt, "@ThisQuestionId", $_SESSION['SecQuestion'], SQLINT4, false, false, 2);
//        scroll right-->>                                                           ^^
```

what is up with the optional max length parameter? shouldn't they both be -1 (max len) or just don't pass them in?? This optional parameter is only valid with strings, see [mssql_bind](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-bind.php)

if this doesn't work, your only other options are to echo the parameters in PHP and record them to a log table from within the procedure.  This way you can be sure you are sending and receiving the proper values in the procedure.

**EDIT**
creating and inserting into a log from SQL is easy, here's how:

create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE MyLog (LogID int not null identity(1,1) primary key
                   ,LogDate datetime not null default GETDATE()
                   ,LogValue varchar(max) not null
                   )
```

Add this in the procedure right after the `SET NOCOUNT ON;`

```
INSERT INTO MyLog 
    (LogValue) 
    VALUES (ISNULL(OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID), 'unknown')
               +', '+ISNULL('"'+CONVERT(varchar(15),@ThisContactId)+'"','NULL')
               +', '+ISNULL('"'+CONVERT(varchar(15),@ThisQuestionId)+'"','NULL')
               +', '+ISNULL('"'+@ThisAnswer+'"','NULL')
           )
```

After you run your application use this to see what you get in the log:

```
SELECT * FROM MyLog ORDER BY LogID
```

that should give you a better idea of what the actual parameters SQL Server is using with in the query.

Comment: to JRod - I added get_last_message and it returned "Changed database context to 'HRAPPS'"

Comment: to KM - I took out the length parameters completely, but that wasnt any help... sorry.  I am going to try to do as you suggested and log them into a table to see the actual values of the variables being passed, but wouldnt that have the same effect as echoing them before the stored procedure is called?   When I did echo them, they were correct.  I can use those same values manually from within sql management studio and I get a result.

Comment: @Rick Knierim, you need log them into a table from the stored procedure. see my latest edit for how.